# Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ when $y=-1$ of the differential equation $(xy^3 +x^2y^7)\frac{dy}{dx} =1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose a solution of the differential equation

$(xy^3 +x^2y^7)\frac{dy}{dx} =1$

satisfies the initial condition $y(1/4)=1$. Then the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ when $y=-1$

is

(A) $4/3$

(B) $-4/3$

(C) $16/5$

(D)$-16/5$

Cannot separate the two variables and hence cannot come to a solution. It is a 1 mark MCQ question in an exam. There must be some quick method to reach to the answer.

Comment: Thank you @isham...yes it is easy now..god bless.. :)

Comment: yw Krishanu .....

Comment: @Krishanu Dasgupta : A quick method is shown in my answer below.

Comment: Previously asked: [What is $\frac{dy}{dx}|_{y=-1}$ for $(xy^3 + x^2y^7)\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$ given that $y \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171975/what-is-fracdydx-y-1-for-xy3-x2y7-fracdydx-1-given-tha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the inverse function $x(y)$.
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=xy^3 +x^2y^7 \quad\text{with condition}\quad x(1)=\frac14$$
By inspection only, changing the sign of the variable $y$ changes nothing. Thus the function $x(y)$ is even. As a consequence :
$$x(-y)=x(y)\quad\text{especially}\quad x(-1)=x(1)=\frac14$$
So, at point  $(y=-1\:,\:x=\frac14)$ :
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac14(-1)^3 +\left(\frac14\right)^2(-1)^7=-\frac14-\frac{1}{16}=-\frac{5}{16}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{16}{5}$$
$$\text{The correct answer is : (D).}$$

Answer (score 2):

***Simple hint***
$$(xy^3 +x^2y^7)\frac{dy}{dx} =1$$ 
It's Bernouilli's equation
$$(xy^3 +x^2y^7) =x'$$
$$x'-xy^3 =x^2y^7$$
$$\frac {x'}{x^2}-\frac {y^3}x =y^7$$
Substitute $z=\frac 1x$
$$z'+zy^3 =-y^7$$
It's easy to solve now

Comment: You can find the answer without solving the equation. Since $x'(y)$ is odd in $y$, $x(y)$ must be even in $y$. However this means the solution isn't invertible in $y$ unless you restrict $y \ge 0$, or write the solution in an implicit form $F(x,y) = 0$ instead of a function $y(x)$. This problem is not well-posed

Comment: Yep thats possible too ..I thought so too in the beginning when I read the question...The op wanted a solution to the equation..